# overriding template of multi user in RollerworksMultiUserBundle Symfony2

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, overriding, multi-user

I use RollerworksMultiUserBundle over FOSUserBundle to handle multi user but i cant override template of each bundle seperatly
I have 2 bundle

1. AdminBundle
2. DesignerBundle

I override AdminBundle but DesignerBundle template was overrided ! 
I try to  override DesignerBundle but this error accured

> Bundle "RollerworksMultiUserBundle" is directly extended by two bundles "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in there:
[rollerworkers](https://github.com/rollerworks/RollerworksMultiUserBundle/blob/master/docs/creating_classes_by_hand.md#34-make-your-bundle-configurable)